# Adsense not working on website at all

Tags: html, web, adsense

I have been trying to implement adsense a while now on my website `www.snoddingcreative.com`. Ive recently reconfigured the account and implemented a new ad on `http://www.snoddingcreative.com/indexgogad20315.htm` as a preliminary test page to the index page. There is a space where the ads would appear but the ads arent appearing.

Also I instigated adsense as a youtube partner and it says my account is one step from being activated and to place code on my youtube channel. I dont think theres a place to put code there but i put it as a comment on that page.

http://www.youtube.com/user/SnoddingCreative
    
    
    
    
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});

Place the ad code
We'll take it from here.
Once you've completed your last steps, you can sit back and relax. We'll get to work on the last step on our end for full activation of your account. When we're done, we'll send you an email to let you know." -->

THEN

I created an ad unit and implemented it further down on `http://www.snoddingcreative.com/indexgogad20315.htm`

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- widget sidebar -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-7344356299990756"
data-ad-slot="4792762622"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: was your account previously disabled?

Comment: interestingly we just configured it on the hosting side so maybe it will work hope so waiting 8-48 hours to see

Comment: yes keep patience to get reviewed

Comment: i sent 12 support ticket feedback including 3 sales requests. The issue is that the account is still under review and the ads are blank until code is implemented. Its asking me to implement code on my youtube partner site though youtube.com/user/snoddingcreative and there is no mechanism to implement code here. 
https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/2594929#ts=2593077
Does anyone know how to get around this or get ahold of support for this? thank you